# sequence given by integral

Tags: sequences-and-series

Its possible to show that the sequence $a_n=\int_{1}^{n}\frac{sin^2x}{x}$dx is monotonic?

I tried evaluet that integral but not helped. I also should be able to prov that without any theorem of convergence, just the proof that converges, can someone give me some ideias for start?

Comment: Show that $a_{n+1} - a_n$ is always positive.

Comment: Indefinite integral of any non-negative function is montonic.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be stupid to consider
$$f(t)=\int_1^t\frac{\sin ^2(x)}{x}\,dx$$ and use the fundamental theorem of calculus to get
$$f'(t)=\frac{\sin ^2(t)}{t}~~>~~0$$

If, *for further purposes*, you want to compute the integral, use one integration by parts writing
$$\int\frac{\sin ^2(x)}{x}\,dx=\frac 12 \int \frac {1-\cos(2x)}{x}\,dx=\frac 12 \log(x)-\frac 12\int \frac {\cos(2x)}{x}\,dx$$
$$\int \frac {\cos(2x)}{x}\,dx=\frac{\sin (2 x)}{2 x}+\int\frac{\sin (2 x)}{2 x^2}\,dx=\text{Ci}(2 x)$$
$$a_n=\int_1^n\frac{\sin ^2(x)}{x}\,dx=\frac{1}{2} (\text{Ci}(2)-\text{Ci}(2 n)+\log (n)) $$ which would not be of much help for your present problem.